# Javascript Date Sorting

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript date sorting by  convert the string in to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365116/javascript-date-sorting-by-convert-the-string-in-to-date-format)

Hi,

```
2010-11-08 18:58:50
2010-11-09 17:49:42
2010-11-09 17:49:42
2010-11-24 19:44:51
2010-11-09 13:54:46
2010-11-23 20:06:29
2010-11-23 20:06:04
2010-11-15 17:51:37
.....................
..............
..........
```

like this i have n number of string formats .How can i convert these strings in to date format and sort accordingly....please

Thanks in advance, Joseph

Comment: _like this i have n number of string formats_ : Where? How?

Comment: Looks like almost exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365116/javascript-date-sorting-by-convert-the-string-in-to-date-format

Comment: That only looks like one format to me, and a simple lexical sort will work on it.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using ISO date formats you can simply sort them lexically.

```
var dates = [
    '2010-11-08 18:58:50',
    '2010-11-09 17:49:42',
    // and so on...
];

dates.sort();
```

For more information on sorting: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 1):

The dates are already in a form that is suitable for sorting. So all you need to do is call `array.sort()`.

Answer (score 0):

i bet this one can help

[how-can-i-convert-a-date-value-in-utc-format-to-a-date-object-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498578/how-can-i-convert-a-date-value-in-utc-format-to-a-date-object-in-javascript)