# ES5 sort() and dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, ecmascript-5

I have a number of objects in an array. The objects have a 'time' property which is a date string.

```
items = [
  {time: "2013-03-01T10:46:11Z"},
  {time: "2013-03-03T10:46:11Z"},
  {time: "2013-03-02T10:46:11Z"}
]
```

I wish to sort the array by that 'time' property.

I've read [How to sort an object array by date property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date) and [Javascript Date Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365671/javascript-date-sorting), but I can't seem to make either of these solutions (either converting to Date objects or sorting as strings) work.

My sort function:

```
items.sort(function(first, second){
  return new Date(first.time) < new Date(second.time) ? 1 : -1;
})
```

Testing the results:

```
items.forEach(function(item){
  console.log(item.time)
})
```

Returns:

```
2013-03-01T10:46:11Z
2013-03-03T10:46:11Z
2013-03-02T10:46:11Z
```

March 1, March 3, March 2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can sort those dates as simple strings, if they're all "Z" dates (Universal Time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the field "date" instead of "time" in your comparator function. Also, the function should return an integer, not a boolean:

```
  return new Date(first.time) - new Date(second.time);
```

That may not work in all browsers. If all your times are Universal Time, just compare them as strings:

```
  return first.time > second.time ? 1 : first.time === second.time ? 0 : -1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've fixed the demo to use consistent names (and return -1 per Array.sort() docs). Edit: I see the problem is solved.

Comment: Pardon the decade-long wait to accept the answer.